# How to identify equivalence in a string?

Tags: c#, comparison

How can I find equivalent(Not equal) values between strings?

```
//Equivalent Values
string A = "Beneficiation Return";
string B = "Return Beneficiation";
string C = "Beneficiation From Return";
string D = "Return From Beneficiation";
```

if i use

```
if(A == B)//Equal
```

It will only compare Equal strings and they are equivalent but not equal, is there any way to verify equivalence?

> Equivalence can be: shuffled words, have or not linking words(Just
>   five:For,To,In,From,At.) or be shuffled and with linking words

the code would results in:

```
("Beneficiation Return" == "Return Beneficiation")True
("Beneficiation From Return" == "Return Beneficiation")True
("Return Beneficiation" == "Return From  Beneficiation")True
```

Comment: Define "Equivalent", then translate your definition into code.

Comment: What's the difference between equal and equivalent in your world?

Comment: Are you trying to see if the strings are semantically equal and not syntactically? If so you're in the realm of NLP and AI, which the language doesn't offer out of the box. You have to define those rules yourself.

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you mean with "equivalent" compared to "equal"? What are your criterias? Do you mean one string contains all the _words_ also contained in the second string? (Then define "word", characters between whitespaces?) As it stands the question is unclear.

Comment: @mm8 Beneficiation Return is Equal to Beneficiation Return | Beneficiation Return is equivalent to Return Beneficiation

Comment: @RenéVogt "Do you mean one string contains all the words also contained in the second string" yeah, but sometimes they have 'linking words' as 'From'

Comment: You could use `string.Split(' ')` and compare the resulting collections...but this only works if "word" as any sequence of characters between spaces and won't therefor work in a lot of languages.

Comment: "sometimes they have linking words"... well that makes it unanswerable. if you can't define clear criterias. PowerdByOrange is right and you need an AI to identify the "words".

Comment: @RenéVogt even if i remove all of those? "From" "In" "To"

Comment: Removing "from", "in", etc maybe one thing, but until you define specifically what _equivalence_ means, you're chasing a fuzzy target.  Are "returns of beneficiation", "returns by means of beneficiation", "returns via beneficiation", "Return benefication" (alternate spelling) all examples of equivalence?  Without going AI route, you need to define hard and fast rules (in mathematical-like terms) of what constitutes equivalence.  As humans it's easy for us to _judge_ what is and is not equivalent - for computers, it's specific definition to make that calculation.

Comment: @LB2 Yes they are all equivalent but it won't happen in my language, from,it,in,to and some few others is the maximum variety, just the other words will change and always be equivalent but Shuffled

Comment: Right, so you need to come up with explicit definition of what constitutes _equivalence_, and work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for..

```
string a = "Beneficiation Return";
string b = "Return Beneficiation";
string c = "Beneficiation From Return";
string d = "Return From Beneficiation";

bool isSame = !a.Except(b).Any() && !b.Except(a).Any();
```

The bool `isSame` will return `true` because strings `a` & `b` contain the same characters.
Compare `a` with `c` and it will return `false`

Comment: Thanks, removing the 'linking words' and using this it worked

Comment: ...unless the words are cased differently, like `"benefication Return"`

Comment: True.. a simple `ToLower()` on both strings would prevent this

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper function: equivalentStrings that accepts both A and B. In that function you could do the following:

1. Split both strings A and B, and get two arrays of words
2. Check if they have same count of words (return false if not)
3. Check each word in arrayA if there is same word in arrayB, if yes remove the word from both arrays if not return false
4. If arrayA is empty (all words removed) return true.